# What should be the size of SQLite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on a data entry application which have only 3 tables with total 30 columns. I want to restrict the number of records in my application. How much space / number of records should I allow so that my app will not eat up devices memory.

**EDIT:**All my table contains only string or numeric type fields not any other fields like BLOB and I am providing search and update facility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much space as your app requires to be usable.

If you have no way of searching or filtering, more than a few dozen rows tends to be overwhelming from a UI perspective.

Unless you are storing larges Blobs in the columns, you will probably hit hundreds of thousands of rows before you start having a noticeable impact on memory.

In all honesty without details about what data types you are storing along with how the data is being used it's hard to make a recommendation.

Comment: My app provides search and update features and I dont have any BLOB field in my db.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, the size should be 2GB. However, I've tried to create a dummy database w/ size of 2GB, it pops an error. After searching for a while, I found out 1GB is the max, I tried and  it succeeded. You can call `getMaximumSize()` in `SQLiteDatabase` class to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

How many records are you talking about? You're talking thousands of rows for it to grow to any substantial size. Edit: As below, unless you import large blob fields.

Each row could be different in size too depending on the different types of data entered.